# Formatting Ruby's prettyprint

Tags: ruby, pretty-print

Is it possible to change the width that prettyprint (`require 'pp'`) uses when formatting output? For example:

```
"mooth"=>["booth", "month", "mooch", "morth", "mouth", "mowth", "sooth", "tooth"]
"morth"=>["forth",
 "mirth",
 "month",
 "mooth",
 "morph",
 "mouth",
 "mowth",
 "north",
 "worth"]
```

The first array is printed inline because it fits within the column width prettyprint allows (79 characters)... the second is split onto multiple lines, because it does not. But I can find no method for changing the column that this behavior starts on.

`pp` depends on `PrettyPrint` (which has ways to allow different widths for the buffer). Is there any way to change the default column width for `pp`, without rewriting it from scratch (accessing `PrettyPrint` directly)?

Alternately, is there a similar ruby gem that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'pp'
mooth = [
  "booth", "month", "mooch", "morth",
  "mouth", "mowth", "sooth", "tooth"
]
PP.pp(mooth, $>, 40)
# => ["booth",
# =>  "month",
# =>  "mooch",
# =>  "morth",
# =>  "mouth",
# =>  "mowth",
# =>  "sooth",
# =>  "tooth"]
PP.pp(mooth, $>, 79)
# => ["booth", "month", "mooch", "morth", "mouth", "mowth", "sooth", "tooth"]
```

To change the default with a monkey patch:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'pp'

class PP
  class << self
    alias_method :old_pp, :pp
    def pp(obj, out = $>, width = 40)
      old_pp(obj, out, width)
    end
  end
end

mooth = ["booth", "month", "mooch", "morth", "mouth", "mowth", "sooth", "tooth"]
pp(mooth)
# => ["booth",
# =>  "month",
# =>  "mooch",
# =>  "morth",
# =>  "mouth",
# =>  "mowth",
# =>  "sooth",
# =>  "tooth"]
```

These methods also work in MRI 1.9.3

Answer (score 9):

Found "ap" aka "Awesome_Print" useful as well from [git-repo](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print)

Code used to test pp and ap:

```
require 'pp'
require "awesome_print" #requires gem install awesome_print 

data = [false, 42, %w{fourty two}, {:now => Time.now, :class => Time.now.class, :distance => 42e42}]
puts "Data displayed using pp command"
pp data

puts "Data displayed using ap command"
ap data
```

O/P from pp vs ap:

```
Data displayed using pp command
[false,
 42,
 ["fourty", "two"],
 {:now=>2015-09-29 22:39:13 +0800, :class=>Time, :distance=>4.2e+43}]

Data displayed using ap command
[
    [0] false,
    [1] 42,
    [2] [
        [0] "fourty",
        [1] "two"
    ],
    [3] {
             :now => 2015-09-29 22:39:13 +0800,
           :class => Time < Object,
        :distance => 4.2e+43
    }
]
```

Reference:

- [Stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008847/what-is-difference-between-p-and-pp#9008954)
- [Web citing](http://www.rubyinside.com/awesome_print-a-new-pretty-printer-for-your-ruby-objects-3208.html)

Comment: This is interesting additional information.  It's not, however, really an answer to the question as asked -- to wit, `"fourty", "two"` should be on one line, according to what the OP is looking for.  Also, I think for anyone worth considering which to use, it's worth noting that the `ap` output shown here couldn't be read back in by a ruby eval (specifically because of the array indices being displayed that way), the way `pp` output frequently could be (it only changes whitespace for basic object types -- though the time object clearly shows an exception to that). Just food for thought.