# What is difference between "p" and "pp"?

Tags: ruby

I did do some searching, but can't find an answer to simple question.

What is difference between `p` and `pp` in Ruby? I know you need to `require 'pp'`. Besides that what are the differences?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`p` is used to inspect a variable as a debug aide. It works printing the output of the method `#inspect`. For example `p foo` will output the content of `foo.inspect`.

Sometimes you need to debug complex variables or nested variables. In this case `p` will output a long line that is hard to understand. Instead, `pp` will put try to arrange the content of the variable so that it is easier to understand, for example indenting nested arrays or using one line for each instance variable of a complex object. `pp` does this calling the `#pretty_inspect` method (the `pp` library adds `#pretty_inspect` methods to many classes such as `String`, `Array` or `Struct`).

To remember: `p` = print, `pp` = pretty print.

Answer (score 6):

They differ slightly.

```
data = [false, 42, %w{fourty two}, {:now => Time.now, :class => Time.now.class, :distance => 42e42}]
p data
  [false, 42, ["fourty", "two"], {:now=>2012-01-25 19:23:06 +0000, :class=>Time, :distance=>4.2e+43}]
pp data
  [false,
   42,
   ["fourty", "two"],
   {:now=>2012-01-25 19:23:06 +0000, :class=>Time, :distance=>4.2e+43}]
```

Please note: I stole the test data from a site showing the [difference between pp and their gem](http://www.rubyinside.com/awesome_print-a-new-pretty-printer-for-your-ruby-objects-3208.html).

Comment: Even like the "ap" aka  "Awesome Print" one mentioned there, with an overhead of gem installing it "gem install awesome_print" 

Data displayed using ap command
'[
    [0] false,
    [1] 42,
    [2] [
        [0] "fourty",
        [1] "two"
    ],
    [3] {
             :now => 2015-09-29 22:39:13 +0800,
           :class => Time < Object,
        :distance => 4.2e+43
    }
]'

Comment: I'm getting the same output for `p` and `pp` in rails console.
Would you know why?

Answer (score 3):

`p` prints a String representation of an object, followed by a newline. So does `puts`. The difference is that `puts` uses `to_s` to convert the argument to a String, and `p` uses `inspect`. This means `p` is often more useful for debugging than `puts`.

`pp` is "pretty print"; it uses `pretty_inspect` to obtain a String representation of an object.

Comment: Your wording is confusing. If `p` is like `puts` and `pp` is like `p`, then all three will be alike. The question is asking the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I have updated the answer. The reason I posted another answer here is because the others missed the key point that `p` uses `inspect` and `puts` uses `to_s`.

Comment: @MattBriggs: I followed the link you provided, and it doesn't mention pretty_inspect.