# not able to get authentication token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, twitter

I tried to use twitter api with ruby for exact search. But because of new twitter api i am not able to access the json file.

this is link 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23superbowl&result_type=recent

Can you please tell me how to fetch json file.

I have posted my rb file , plz help

```
# http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html 
require 'open-uri'
# https://github.com/flori/json
require 'json'
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008847/what-is-difference-between-p-and-pp
require 'pp'
require 'twitter'
#load 'twitter_config.rb'
#Create seprate config file.
#Encrprty ur keys using md5.

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "3OpBStixWSMAzBttp6UWON7QA"
  config.consumer_secret = "MBmfQXoHLY61hYHzGYU8n69sQRQPheXJDejP1SKE2LBdgaqRg4"
  config.access_token = "322718806-qScub4diRzggWUO9DaLKMVKwXZcgrqHD2OFbwQTr"
  config.access_token_secret = "aWAIxQVnqF3nracQ0cC0HbRbSDxlCAaUIICorEAPlxIub"
end 
# Construct the URL we'll be calling
print "please enter phrase you want to search"
phrase_value=gets.chomp;
#pets = File.open("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#{phrase_value}", "r");

request_uri = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=";
request_query = ''
url = "#{request_uri}#{phrase_value}"
url.gsub!(' ','%20')
print url;

# Actually fetch the contents of the remote URL as a String.
buffer = open(url).read

# Convert the String response into a plain old Ruby array. It is faster and saves you time compared to the standard Ruby libraries too.
result = JSON.parse(buffer)
# An example of how to take a random sample of elements from an array. Pass the number of elements you want into .sample() method. It's probably a better idea for the server to limit the results before sending, but you can use basic Ruby skills to trim & modify the data however you'd like.
result = result.sample(5)

# Loop through each of the elements in the 'result' Array & print some of their attributes.
 result.each do |tweet|
  puts "Count       Username                tweet"           
  puts "(#{tweet.url})    #{tweet.user.screen_name} #{tweet.text}";
  #sleep(3);
  #count=count+1;
  #before following user check if its alreay in list using bollean. 
  client.follow("#{tweet.user.screen_name}")
end
puts "Finished!\n\n"
```

Comment: If those are your real secret tokens, you may want to change them, now...

Comment: Also you should be using `url = request_uri  + URI::encode(phrase_value)` to actually escape the search query instead of just replacing spaces...

Comment: @BradWterth no its not, but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @papirtiger i have to do exact match , and for that i am using twitter search api with double quotes. But its not returning proper values. Still its returning keyword search. Can you please suggest any way to do that.

Comment: The [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) does not take the `q` parameter wrapped in quotes. Try on https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'json'
require 'oauth'
require 'pp'

consumer_key        = 'xxxx'
consumer_secret     = 'xxxx'
access_token        = 'xxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxx'

consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(
  consumer_key,
  consumer_secret,
  site:'https://api.twitter.com/'
)
endpoint = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer, access_token, access_token_secret)


puts "please enter phrase you want to search"
phrase_value=gets.chomp;


request_uri = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#{phrase_value}";

# GET
response = endpoint.get("#{request_uri}")
result = JSON.parse(response.body)

pp result
```

Comment: thank you for your help sir,  i have used same method . it really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Since you already are using the Twitter gem why not use its search methods instead of rolling your own:

```
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "3OpBStixWSMAzBttp6UWON7QA"
  config.consumer_secret = "MBmfQXoHLY61hYHzGYU8n69sQRQPheXJDejP1SKE2LBdgaqRg4"
  config.access_token = "322718806-qScub4diRzggWUO9DaLKMVKwXZcgrqHD2OFbwQTr"
  config.access_token_secret = "aWAIxQVnqF3nracQ0cC0HbRbSDxlCAaUIICorEAPlxIub"
end 

print "please enter phrase you want to search"
search_query = gets.chomp;

# @see https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Search.md
client.search(search_query, result_type: "recent").each do |tweet|
  puts "Count       Username                tweet"           
  puts "(#{tweet.url})    #{tweet.user.screen_name} #{tweet.text}";
end
```

Comment: thanks sir, sir i have done it in same way . But thry want json file and to store some where so i have used search api call. Thanks for your help