# How to get API and manipulate it

Tags: ruby, http

With Ruby, no Rails, how can I call an API such as http://api.anapi.com/, and later get a value and check if it is greater than 5?

If it contains an array called `anarray` which contains hashes, in one of those hashes I want to get to the value of the key `key`.

Right now I use:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://api.cryptocoincharts.info/tradingPair/eth_btc")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

And I get: `#<StringIO:0x2cadb90>`

Figured it out:

```
# http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html 
require 'open-uri'
# https://github.com/flori/json
require 'json'
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008847/what-is-difference-between-p-and-pp
require 'pp'

buffer = open('http://api.cryptocoincharts.info/tradingPair/eth_btc').read

# api_key = "FtHwuH8w1RDjQpOr0y0gF3AWm8sRsRzncK3hHh9"

result = JSON.parse(buffer)

puts result["markets"]
# result.each do |user|
#   puts "#{user['id']}\t#{user['name']}\t#{user['email']}"
#   puts "Registered: #{user['created_at']}\n\n"
# end

# my_hash = JSON.parse('{"hello": "goodbye"}')
# puts my_hash["hello"] => "goodbye"
```

Comment: There is no need to use Rails. There are tons of [HTTP Clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) out there that could help you to interact with an API. Or do you want to know how to do that without any gem at all?

Comment: I wouldn't use Net::HTTP, instead I'd use OpenURI. it's an easier interface to use and is perfect for simple calls to an API. Also, you don't have a bug or a problem with your existing code, you just didn't try hard enough to solve the problem. You are partway through to finding a working solution since you took the harder path by using Net::HTTP. More research on your part would have put you way ahead.

Comment: If you figured it out, you should put your code into an answer, then wait until Stack Overflow's grace period expires, and then select it as the answer. Don't add it to your question; Questions are for just that, the question. Answers are for answers.

Comment: @theTinMan: open-uri's friendlier interface comes at a great cost :) http://sakurity.com/blog/2015/02/28/openuri.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Net::HTTP](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html):

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html?count=10')
Net::HTTP.get(uri) # => String
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the data. If for example the API returns JSON, you can parse the String with Ruby's [JSON module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).

Comment: Do I need to so anything in addition to adding require "net/https" to my code?

Comment: @Pabi no, that's it. I updated the answer to include `require 'net/http'
`.

Comment: @Pabi that's too broad to answer. `Net::HTTP.get(uri)` returns the data in form of a String, so you can manipulate it however you need to. For example if the API returns JSON, you can use the [json module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) to parse it into JSON.