# How to modify font-size in simple form

Tags: html, css, ruby, simple-form

```
<style>

.mobile_note_form2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}    

</style>

<div class="mobile_note_form2">
<fieldset>
    <%= f.date_select :created_at %><br/><br/>
  <%= f.text_area :note %><br/>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Note"  %>

</fieldset>
</div>
```

I want to make the "Remove Note" label with a font-size of 30px, but can't seem to figure out how to change styles in simple form.

Comment: Are you able to solve your issue now? or are you still stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `span` with a `class` and use that class to set the `font-size`.

```
<span class="largeFont" ><%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Note"  %></span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.largeFont
{
   font-size : 30px;
}
```

Remove `class mobile_note_form2`  from the `div`. It is causing all the elements to have `font-size : 30px`

Comment: I did exactly that and there still was no change :(

Comment: Can you provide a JS Fiddle. May be i will be able to help you better.

Comment: I've never used JS Fiddle before, but is this what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/Ethanph89/ttk3mvp0/

Comment: which template are you usign for `HTML`?

Comment: Ravi, I'm glad to see you're in good health after that scare in 2012. With regards to some of the other comments, wouldn't you rather have a JS Sitar? Also, you might wish to mention `String#tinyfy`, which, for example, I used in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496273/placing-sub-arrays-in-neat-rows).